# Control similiar to x-ms-webview for Android IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I am developing cross platform app using HTML5+JS.

My application mixes content html files avaiable on device and those opened from web. It is one page navigation (index.html which hosts other local pages) with one page that hosts x-ms-webview (to display external content). I have to use x-ms-webview (or some other form of browser in browser solution) for two reasons:

1. If I open external urls just like local ones, css is loaded but JS files are not.
2. I need to use backbutton to navigate to previous pages (so manual load of external page to index.html is not really an option as this requires building own history handling).

I have working version but it uses x-ms-webview which is avaiable only on Windows Phone.

I need similiar control that works on Android and IOS (or some other solution to my problem).

Comment: Would an `iframe` work?

Comment: I did not try it. It could be solution but some pages cannot be displayed in iframe

Comment: I have tried using IFrame. For WP it does not work (not sure why), but it is not a problem as i can use x-ms-webview there. For android I get "Blocked a frame with origin '...'  from accessing a cross-origin frame." error whenever I navigate external page but beside that pages work. How can i get rid of this error?